How can the compiler affect the way logical values are represented in Fortran?
This question is based on these 2 other questions [1] [2], but I figured I'd get more progress if I asked something less specific and worked by myself from there.
According to an user in the first post, depending on the compiler, the values used by Fortran to represent the logical type could vary:

Fortran's logical values do not necessarily map to 0 and 1 as in C or Matlab; rather, the mapping is compiler-dependent.

Assuming his statement is correct, I do not understand how or why. Why is it the case? Why would different compilers not represent a well-stablished data type in the same way? If standardization of data type representation is not a reasonable expectation, why is it not so in Fortran but is the case for the other big languages exemplified? Is it a case of a historical left-over, or is there a good reason for that?
And what are those ways? How could I even determine what my compiler does? Is it in the documentation or can I determine it based on the code output?
Lastly, does using a C wrapper like in the original examples make it more likely a certain choice will be made, or does it not matter at all?
I wasn't able to find much on the issue, albeit I suspect that is because I don't know the right keywords to search for it. Any help shedding light on the matter would be appreciated.
Context
If the context is at all relevant, the compiler I personally used was Mingw-64 6.3, but it was done inside Matlab 2022a with whatever Mex adds. The compiled file was this Lapack C wrapper for Matlab, which can be found here.
I've had some trouble with calling it from within a Simulink subsystem block as the vector containing the logical flags seem to be ignored there regardless of data type (int64/32/16, float, logical, string and int8 not even accepted). Upon calling the 'dtrsen' function with the correct flags, the resulting eigenvalues vector comes out unordered and seemingly random, unlike when I do the same from within a Matlab script, in which the result comes out in descending order of the marked eigenvalues.
To be honest, I've come to personally believe it's probably a Simulink data transfer issue and not a compiler one as the problem doesn't occur when calling the file from within a Matlab script, but I'd like to understand what I'm dealing with better to be sure. I'll still try a few other things, but it's likely I'll end up doing my own S-function at the end of the day, and this knowledge could prevent me from spending hours debugging my mistakes.
Also I'm just a curious guy.
[1] https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/43101/reordering-eigenvalues-in-schur-factorization-matlab-ordschur-and-lapack-dtrse
[2] https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/44497/matlab-ordschur-producing-different-results-from-lapacks-dtrsen-in-simulink
[3] https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16777-lapack

Logical values correspond to .TRUE. and .FALSE. and except for logical of kind c_bool there's not really anything one can meaningfully say about comparing these values with anything but themselves.  One generally doesn't say to a cashier "I can't decide whether to buy a carrot or a penguin. Which one has value 0?".

"Why would the compiler represent the same data type in different ways?" is the wrong question. Ask rather "Why should different compilers represent a data type in the same way". Fortran defines how Logicals work within the language; it cares not how this result is achieved.

@IanBush I see. I believe that's a fair rephrasing of what I meant, as it does more accurately describes what I intended to ask. I'll change the question to reflect that. However, my question still stands because the way data types are represented seems to be consistent across compilers in different languages according to the original comment. I'll change the question to reflect that.

@francescalus I was under the impression that true values were generally mapped to a "lit bit" universally. It's even in the power switches right? Sure, you could map 1 and 0 to "penguin"/"carrot", but that would be arbitrary. However, "true" and "false" do have historical and societal precedent in coding for being mapped to bits in certain ways, which one could call the "intuitive" meanings. It feels unfair to call it arbitrary, even though I can see that might be only in my point of view.

A compiler could, for example, map a 32-bit logical true/false values to 'aHp7' and 'xXp0' and use this seemingly strange mapping to detect whether memory has been corrupted when referencing a logical value. Such corruption as a naughty TRANSFER, dodgy argument association or so on. (See also sentinel values in reals and the numerous IEEE NaNs.)

I see, that does make sense. Thank you for the information, I guess embedding more information than a simple "true" or "false" in the data is indeed a good reason for a seemingly "esoteric" mapping.

You can see how MEX does interesting things with Fortran logicals, etc.,  in this other question.

@francescalus wow, that's actually very relevant to my prior question. Thank you.

As previously mentioned, the Fortran standard does not define the internal details of what is meant by .TRUE. and .FALSE..  It does however require that a default logical entity occupies one numeric storage unit, which is the amount of storage that also holds a default integer or real.  Some Fortran processors use the low order bit of an integer to represent these values.  The other bits in the integer can then used as a payload.

Even in C, I'm not sure that the standard specifies how a bool has to be represented in memory. It specifies how it should be casted to/from integer types, but it's not exactly the same thing.

@PierU I see, so the assumption made by the original commenter was most likely not entirely correct or a simplification? That would make sense.

I discuss this issue in https://stevelionel.com/drfortran/2000/04/29/doctor-fortran-in-to-eqv-or-to-neqv-that-is-the-question-or-its-only-logical/

The great thing about standards is that there are so many of them.  Even in Windows, there are two different standard "true" values; TRUE defines as 1, but the COM boolean truth value is -1.

@SteveLionel that blogpost was pretty good, as it explained in depth what was commented here. Thanks!
The blog actually seems pretty neat overall, covers some topics I wouldn't get to know about otherwise.

@Craig Yeah, I'm learning that now - it seems standards aren't so standard after all. Coming from an engineering background, it feels a bit weird, as standards are usually somewhat regular even if they vary from country to country. Well, living and learning and crying and learning and god damn it my code still won't work ;-; (still having fun at least, like a painful exercise kind of fun but fun nonetheless)

The standards of the high level languages carefully avoid specifying the implementation details, as much as possible. This is not a bug, this is a feature, in order to give the compilers enough flexibility to produce an efficient binary code whatever the hardware architecture.

@PierU That makes sense, it's a shame it also creates these kinds of problems as a colateral.

The real issue is using integer values in place of a boolean type. In C and all derived languages there are historical reasons. In Fortran this is not allowed by the standard, even if some compilers allow that as an extension. Using integer values is IMO a bad practice that should be avoided.

There are just two different values, .false. and .true. for the logical type (and the default kind). The exact implementation in memory is not specified by the standard. If the processor is based on binary representation, all bits 0 is an obvious choice for the .false. value, so you will not see anything else in practice. But what about .true.? Is the lowest bit set to 1 or all bits set to 1 the more obvious choice? One represents an integer value of 1, the other -1, for two-complement signed integers.
The logical value of other bit patterns, than those used for the .false. and .true. values, is not defined by the standard.
